# Issue while updating and removing users

Tags: authentication, active-directory-module

Sitecore version : 9.0.2

We are using AD authentication to authenticate users. When we are creating new users ( AD users), they are getting created without any issue.However after creating the users, when we try to update the users settings ( for eg : mapping additional role) or removing the user from sitecore, we get below :

```
13184 04:57:29 INFO  AUDIT (AD\XXXXX): Delete user: AD\XXXXX
13184 04:57:30 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Nested Exception



Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.ContinuationManager.ResumePipeline(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.ContinuationManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

In AD membership provider config, we have below settings :

[image]

The connectionusername provided has only read access to the ad group. We dont delete the AD users in active directory.

This may be reason, we are getting the access denied error when we try to update/delete the users from sitecore as it might be trying the update the user in AD and since it doesnt have the correct access rights, throwing error.

My question is, Is there any way, i can skip the **updation/deletion in AD** and continue with normal administration activity ( such as adding new roles in sitecore) etc

Comment: This activity "when we try to update the users settings ( for eg : mapping additional role) or removing the user from sitecore" - has to be done in AD , not required in Sitecore

Comment: We put users in a special AD group and use that to filter out unwanted users.